# How is literal_eval() here is helping to fix the error?

Tags: python

I have a pandas dataframe, which has a column called location, it has geo coordinates and the dtype is object as seen below.

[image]

I would like to use the values (as below) in this column to calculate the distance but I get the error as str cannot be accepted, only number type

[image]

But when literal_eval function is applied (as in first screenshot) on the column, I am able to calculate the distance between the coordinates.

[image]

I would like to understand what did literal_eval do to fix this error.

Comment: It changed a string into a number.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga but the dtype still shows as object, so you are saying that values in the object has been changed to number from string? and how does literal_eval do that?

Comment: Object doesn't mean `str` it mean some kind of Python object. You have a string representing `tuple` objects with `int` objects inside of them. You use literal_eval to evaluate that string as a Python object literal, and you get a column of `tuple` objects. I'm not sure what you mean by "how". It does it the same way the Python parser/compiler/interpreter parses your source-code strings as objects.

Comment: Did you read and understand https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval?